# POST request with formidable returning 500 - Node.js

Tags: node.js, formidable

I need to save data and file as a new project to my Mongo. For this I am using formidable.
My POST method looks like this:

```
exports.create = async (req, res) => {
  let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    if (err) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Image could not be uploaded' }] });
    }

    const {
      title,
      description,
      photo,
      tags,
      git,
      demo,
      projectType,
    } = fields;


    //get links object
    const projectFields = {};
    projectFields.creator = req.user._id;
    if (title) projectFields.title = title;
    if (title) projectFields.description = description;
    if (photo) projectFields.photo = photo;
    if (projectType) projectFields.projectType = projectType;
    if (tags) {
      projectFields.tags = tags.split(',').map((tag) => tag.trim());
    }

    //get links object
    projectFields.links = {};
    if (git) projectFields.links.git = git;
    if (demo) projectFields.links.demo = demo;


    //1kb = 1000
    //1mb = 1000000kb
    //name 'photo' mus match client side. use photo
    if (files.photo) {
      if (files.photo.size > 1000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          errors: [{ msg: 'Image could not be uploaded. File to big.' }],
        });
      }
      //this relates to data in schema product
      project.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
      project.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
    }
  });
```

I want to use async/await so I am using `try{}catch(err){}` for my `project.save()`. I am initializing all my fields where I have also nested links. Unfortunately this is not working as I thought it will work. Right now my `POST` is returning 500. I am sitting on this and right now I am at the point that this can get a bit messy and not even close to any solution.

Comment: Do you by chance have the output of the error from console logs?

Comment: nope. console is empty :/ I am using postman for this